# Would there be more amino acid residues in the extracellular or intercellular space?

Tags: cell-biology, bioinformatics

I am working on a bioinformatics project with HMMs and want to write some initiation probabilities for the location of amino acid residues. I know for different transmembrane proteins there will be different cases, but, in general, which regions of the protein would correspond to more AA residues: intracellular or extracellular? Or is there no general pattern?

Comment: This would probably vary a lot with cell type, is there a certain type you're interested in?

Comment: Not really, I was wondering more in general terms. It makes sense that there is a lot of variety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ,there are some patterns.
First you have to determine which group of membrane proteins you're talking about.
According to ***Molecular Cell Biology Lodish et al 8th ed chapter 13***, there are 6 types of ER membrane proteins ( and therefore in the cell membrane)

The 6 types are type 1,type 2 ,type 3 , type 4,Tail anchored proteins ,GPI anchored proteins.
Nearly all AA residues in type 3 or  the tail-anchored type are located in the cytosolic side of the membrane ( their difference is in their N/C terminus orientation) whereas GPI anchored type has almost its entire AA residues in the exoplasmic side.

For other types there may not be a general pattern.

***See E. Hartmann et al., 1989, P. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA
86:5786, and C. A. Brown and S. D. Black, 1989, J. Biol. Chem. 264:4442.***

By the way , you can also think of it in another way. Antigens , Hormone Receptors , Structral proteins in exoplasmic leaflet of membrane usually have more AA in the exoplasmic side.